# How do i sum rows/columns that are changing depending on the users input?

Tags: excel, vba, sum

Im having issues where I'm trying to have a cell where it adds all the cartons per skid together. The number of rows will change depending on the number of skids and lines. In this case, I would want the sum of k3 for skid 1 and sum of k4:k5 for skid 2 and etc. These lines will consistently change depending on the skid number and the number of lines. Is there a way to add all these skids per skid number? Below I attached an imagine in regards to this issue

```
Sub InsertRows()

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim row As Integer
Dim col As Integer

  Do
    'Retrieve an answer from the user
      x = Application.InputBox("Number of Lines Per skid", "Number of lines per skid", Type:=1)
      y = Application.InputBox("Skid Number", " What is the skid number", Type:=1)
      

    'Check if user selected cancel button
    
      If x = 0 Then Exit Sub
      
      'insert rows with a loop
      For row = 1 To x
          Range("3:3").EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
      Next row
      
      Range("A3").Value = y
      
      'merge columns with a loop
      For col = 1 To 8
          Range(Cells(3, col), Cells(3 + x - 1, col)).Merge
          Range(Cells(3, col), Cells(3 + x - 1, col)).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlThin
          Cells.RowHeight = 15.75
          Columns.ColumnWidth = 12
          Range("2:2").RowHeight = 35
      Next col
      
      For col = 2 To 4
           Range(Cells(3, col), Cells(3 + x - 1, col)).Interior.Color = RGB(195, 224, 180)
      Next col
      
      For col = 5 To 5
          Range(Cells(3, col), Cells(3 + x - 1, col)).Formula = "= (B3 * C3 * D3) / 1728"
      Next col
        
      For col = 6 To 6
          Range(Cells(3, col), Cells(3 + x - 1, col)).Interior.Color = RGB(195, 224, 180)
          Range(Cells(3, col), Cells(3 + x - 1, col)).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlThin
      Next col
      
      For col = 7 To 7
          Range(Cells(3, col), Cells(3 + x - 1, col)).Formula = "= F3/E3"
      Next col
      
      For col = 8 To 8
          Range(Cells(3, col), Cells(3 + x - 1, col)).Formula = "=LOOKUP(G3,HELP!$A$1:$B$11,HELP!$C$1:$C$11)"
      Next col
      
      For col = 9 To 12
          Range(Cells(3, col), Cells(3 + x - 1, col)).Interior.Color = RGB(195, 224, 180)
          Range(Cells(3, col), Cells(3 + x - 1, col)).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlThin
      Next col
      
      For col = 13 To 13
          Range(Cells(3, col), Cells(3 + x - 1, col)).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlThin
      Next col
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A3").Formula = "=IF(Sheet1!B3=FALSE,0,IF(Sheet1!$H3=60,Sheet1!$F3,0))"
    Range("b3").Formula = "=IF(Sheet1!B3=FALSE,0,IF(Sheet1!$H3=65,Sheet1!$F3,0))"
    Range("c3").Formula = "=IF(Sheet1!B3=FALSE,0,IF(Sheet1!$H3=70,Sheet1!$F3,0))"
    Range("d3").Formula = "=IF(Sheet1!B3=FALSE,0,IF(Sheet1!$H3=85,Sheet1!$F3,0))"
    Range("e3").Formula = "=IF(Sheet1!B3=FALSE,0,IF(Sheet1!$H3=92.5,Sheet1!$F3,0))"
    Range("f3").Formula = "=IF(Sheet1!B3=FALSE,0,IF(Sheet1!$H3=100,Sheet1!$F3,0))"
    Range("g3").Formula = "=IF(Sheet1!B3=FALSE,0,IF(Sheet1!$H3=125,Sheet1!$F3,0))"
    Range("h3").Formula = "=IF(Sheet1!B3=FALSE,0,IF(Sheet1!$H3=175,Sheet1!$F3,0))"
    Range("i3").Formula = "=IF(Sheet1!B3=FALSE,0,IF(Sheet1!$H3=250,Sheet1!$F3,0))"
    Range("j3").Formula = "=IF(Sheet1!B3=FALSE,0,IF(Sheet1!$H3=300,Sheet1!$F3,0))"
    Range("k3").Formula = "=IF(Sheet1!B3=FALSE,0,IF(Sheet1!$H3=400,Sheet1!$F3,0))"
    Range("A3:K3").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A3:K74")
    Range("A3:K74").Select
    Range("L3").Select
    
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    
      
  'x will always be bigger than zero OR smaller than 24
  Loop While x > 0 Or x < 24
  
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A3").Formula = "=IF(Sheet1!B3="","",IF(Sheet1!$H$3!=60,Sheet1!$F$3,0))"
    Range("B3").Formula = "=IF(Sheet1!B3="","",IF(Sheet1!$H$3!=65,Sheet1!$F$3,0))"
    Range("C3").Formula = "=IF(Sheet1!B3="","",IF(Sheet1!$H$3!=70,Sheet1!$F$3,0))"
    Range("D3").Formula = "=IF(Sheet1!B3="","",IF(Sheet1!$H$3!=85,Sheet1!$F$3,0))"
    Range("E3").Formula = "=IF(Sheet1!B3="","",IF(Sheet1!$H$3!=92.5,Sheet1!$F$3,0))"
    Range("F3").Formula = "=IF(Sheet1!B3="","",IF(Sheet1!$H$3!=100,Sheet1!$F$3,0))"
    Range("G3").Formula = "=IF(Sheet1!B3="","",IF(Sheet1!$H$3!=125,Sheet1!$F$3,0))"
    Range("H3").Formula = "=IF(Sheet1!B3="","",IF(Sheet1!$H$3!=175,Sheet1!$F$3,0))"
    Range("I3").Formula = "=IF(Sheet1!B3="","",IF(Sheet1!$H$3!=250,Sheet1!$F$3,0))"
    Range("J3").Formula = "=IF(Sheet1!B3="","",IF(Sheet1!$H$3!=300,Sheet1!$F$3,0))"
    Range("K3").Formula = "=IF(Sheet1!B3="","",IF(Sheet1!$H$3!=400,Sheet1!$F$3,0))"

End Sub
```

[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmHWp.png)

Comment: Is this question any different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75513621/trying-to-figure-out-a-way-to-sum-all-the-cartons-per-skid?

Comment: _I'm trying to have a cell_   - Which cell, column L ?

Comment: Yes, it is the same question but with a bit more clarity. Anywhere in column N will be okay for starter

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub InsertRows()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim x As Long, y As Long, row As Long, col As Long
    Dim ar, i As Long
    ar = Array(60, 65, 70, 85, 92.5, 100, 125, 175, 250, 300, 400)

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
 
    Do
        'Retrieve an answer from the user
        'Check if user selected cancel button
        x = Application.InputBox("Number of Lines Per skid", "Number of lines per skid", Type:=1)
        If x = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
        y = Application.InputBox("Skid Number", " What is the skid number", Type:=1)
        If y = 0 Then Exit Sub
        
        'insert rows
        ws1.Rows(2).RowHeight = 35
        ws1.Range("3:3").Resize(x).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        ws1.Range("A3").Value = y
      
        'merge columns with a loop
        For col = 1 To 8
            With ws1.Cells(3, col).Resize(x)
                .Merge
                .BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlThin
                .RowHeight = 15.75
                .ColumnWidth = 12
            End With
        Next col
        
        ws1.Range("B3:D3").Resize(x).Interior.Color = RGB(195, 224, 180)
        ws1.Range("E3").Resize(x).Formula = "= (B3 * C3 * D3) / 1728"
        With ws1.Range("F3").Resize(x)
            .Interior.Color = RGB(195, 224, 180)
            .BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlThin
        End With
        ws1.Range("G3").Resize(x).Formula = "= F3/E3"
        ws1.Range("H3").Resize(x).Formula = "=LOOKUP(G3,HELP!$A$1:$B$11,HELP!$C$1:$C$11)"
        For col = 9 To 12
            With ws1.Cells(3, col).Resize(x)
                .Interior.Color = RGB(195, 224, 180)
                .BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlThin
            End With
        Next
        ws1.Range("M3").Resize(x).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlThin
        
        'total skids
        With ws1.Range("N3")
             .FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC11:R[" & x - 1 & "]C11)"
             .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 127)
             .BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlThin
             .Font.Bold = True
        End With
      
        ' sheet 2
        For i = 0 To UBound(ar)
            ws2.Range("A3").Offset(, i).Formula = "=IF(Sheet1!B3=FALSE,0,IF(Sheet1!$H3=" & ar(i) & ",Sheet1!$F3,0))"
        Next
        ws2.Range("A3:K3").AutoFill Destination:=ws2.Range("A3:K74")
      
       'x will always be bigger than zero OR smaller than 24
    Loop While x > 0 Or x < 24
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(ar)
        ws2.Range("A3").Offset(, i).Formula = "=IF(Sheet1!B3="","",IF(Sheet1!$H$3!=" & ar(i) & ",Sheet1!$F$3,0))"
    Next
    
End Sub
```